# Simulator irregularity?

Tags: simulation, spice

Okay...I thought I should know this, but I've never heard of a diode voltage divider.  I am running a Spice simulation (using MicroCap).  I have an ac input ("Vsource") of magnitude 2V (4Vp-p), capacatively coupled to the input of an LM324 op amp.  The input is protected by two 1N5817 Schottkey diodes.  The idea there being that on the lower diode, negative parts of the input AC wave will cause that diode to conduct, absorbing them into ground.  On the upper diode, positive parts above the supply voltage of 12V will cause that diode to conduct, routing them into the 12V supply line.

When I simulate though, I'm seeing something unexpected.  The simulator seems to think the two diodes act as a voltage divider, because the transient simulation output shows the 4V p-p AC source wave, centered exactly half way between the supply voltage of 12V, at 6V (in light green as V(Vin) below).  DC voltages are shown in the pink rectangles with rounded corners on the schematic.  Don't know if it matters, but frequency is 60Hz.

I'm pretty sure the AC wave should not have a DC offset due to the diodes acting as a divider.  Not sure what's going on, but just in case I wanted to do a sanity check and see if anyone knows if this is indeed an incorrect output, or am I wrong?  Is this one of those times you have to trick the simulator somehow to get a correct result?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure the simulator will do this. The reverse leakage current that defines things will be the same for both diodes because it's a simulation of the same model. It will naturally produce an ideal mid-point voltage of 6 volts. That is what you are seeing of course.

In addition, I see no resistive biasing on the Vin+ input and, in reality, it will float to some indeterminate level. Is this what you really want? It doesn't seem sensible but it's your circuit etc..

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I hadn't considered that the input would need resistive biasing.  I'm not a terribly regular user of op amps, so I just hadn't thought it was a necessity.  Most circuits I see don't use biasing on an op amp input.  Did you mean this input should be biased for this case specifically, in order to get an accurate simulation, or that it should be done with op amp circuits in general?

Comment: You need to bias it for it to work properly in a real circuit. The non-inverting input requires an unambiguous DC bias voltage and the diodes cannot be relied upon to accomplish this.

Comment: *Most circuits I see don't use biasing on an op amp input.* The fact that you don't "see" it doesn't mean it isn't there. Very often the feedback resistors also provide the required biasing. As mentioned, unbiased nodes can be "floating" and have an undefined voltage. Would a circuit with an undefined voltage work in a well defined way?